# Migration SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 - go for vanilla or directly to KB

Tags: 2013, 2016, migration, service-pack

Migration from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 is going to be planned.

Which approach is recommended?

1. Migration to SharePoint 2016 vanilla/RTM version, then installing SP1 and then recent KB after migrating
2. Migration to SharePoint 2016 SP1, then installing recent KB after migrating
3. Migration to SharePoint 2016 SP1 with recent KB

Microsoft best practice just explains migration to the vanilla/RTM Version of SharePoint 2016. No word about updates/Service Pack/KBs.

Maybe someone has done migration and has some experience. I would prefer path 3.

Comment: I would suggest that you read what all the updates and SP1 actually updates and even breaks. and you would still need to test your way, so i guess you have a test-environment for 2016 and could try to upgrade content databases on the go before/after SP1.

Comment: Yes I do have a test environment. And I would double-check the advantages and disadvantages of the KBs. Sure. As I will install Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2016 and maybe some KB on top it would be much more uncomplicated to migrate directly to that state instead of migrating and updating two times. So as I am in planning phase I was interested in experiences of other experts. I will test both/all 3 ways. But maybe there will be things I do not notice while testing and others have made experiences by now. Any answer is welcome!

Comment: It's a big task and often it's individual what's the best approach. Some good sites for reading about the patches can be found here: https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Builds/SharePoint-2016-Builds.aspx and https://sharepointupdates.com/Patches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Go for Option 3.

Even if there is no direct recommendation on TechNet, Microsoft always recommends the use of the most current CU for productive deployments. I have migrated dozends of times since SharePoint 2010 and this always worked fine.

Another thing is the practical perspective: Migrating from SP2013 to SP2016 itself is enough work to do. You do not want the extra-hassle by having to install ServicePacks and Cumulative Updates during your upgrade-process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not sure it was even possible going directly to the newest KB. Will check this with test migration and go this way if test migration works fine.